# Spreadsheet] How do I remove whitespace after a specific character?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

#### Overview

This function is used to translate Japanese into English.

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| ja | en |
| こんにちは,こんにちは,こんばんは | =GOOGLETRANSLATE($A2,$B$1,A$1) |

B2 will output the following

| B |
| --- |
| Good morining, Good afternoon, Good evening |

#### What I want to achieve

I would like to have the output with only the whitespace appearing after the comma removed as follows.

| B |
| --- |
| Good morining,Good afternoon,Good evening |

I found some parts that did not work with all spaces gone or full-width characters, so if you could tell me how to do the above, that would be great.

Comment: I thought that in your formula, `=GOOGLETRANSLATE($A2,$B$1,A$1)` might be `=GOOGLETRANSLATE($A2,A$1,$B$1)`. If my understanding is correct, in your showing sample, I thought that `=REGEXREPLACE(GOOGLETRANSLATE($A2,A$1,$B$1),", ",",")` and `=JOIN(",",ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(GOOGLETRANSLATE($A2,A$1,$B$1),","))))` might be able to be used. But, for example, when `こんにちは。こんにちは。こんばんは。` is translated, `Hello. Hello. Good evening.` is returned. In this case, what result do you want to retrieve? I'm worried about your other samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tanaike described above, it is easy to do that with [`REGEXREPLACE()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245?hl=en). Set it to replace `,` s with `,`, and the spaces after commas will go away.

[Click here to see it in action.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LctNhjHmEOJ4jUI7WEUey7OLwmmbMGMEFYsL6hUCBQ4/edit?usp=sharing)